# I have a line F(t) = a + bt and a surface, S(u,v). Is there a formula for the intersection between those?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

If I have line, `F(t) = a + bt` (where $a$, $b$ are known 3D vectors), and a surface, `S(u,v)`, as an arbitrary algebraic formula, is there any formula/algorithm to find the intersection between those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be your line
$C(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}a_1+b_1t\\a_2+b_2t\\a_3+b_3t\end{array}\right)$,
and let us suppose that your surface is parameterized à la Monge as 
$S(u,v)=\left(\begin{array}{c}u\\v\\f(u,v)\end{array}\right)$.
Then you are seeking the coordinates of points (one or many)
$$p=\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right),$$ 
such that $p\in C$ and $p\in S$.

This leads you to a system of equations given by:
$$\begin{aligned}
a_1+b_1t&=u\\
a_2+b_2t&=v\\
a_3+b_3t&=f(u,v)\;.
\end{aligned}$$

Now you can see that -depending on the data- you'll have that this system may have solutions in five (or more) general cases:

a) The line and the surface don't intersect;

b) The line pass through one or several isolated points;

c) The line is tangent in one or several isolated points;

d) The line is totally embedded on the surface;

e) Any combination of the 4 cases mentioned before.

Can you visualize any other case? Would you like to treat a specific example?

Comment: Thank you! The surface is not parameterized this way, though... is there a way to convert a surface parameterized arbitrarily, such as `S(u,v) = (cos(u), sin(u), v)` (random example) to that way? Also, is there a name for the resulting system so I can look how to solve it?

Comment: To answers: 1) Locally is possible to parameterize any surface à la Monge: for your random example (which is a cylinder) it is $(u,\sqrt{1-u^2},v)$.   2) Name for that? no, it is a simple natural construction, and to solve it you only need to say the line to assemble the equations.

Comment: I see, thank you! This still leaves open the problems of making the conversion and how to solve the resulting system, but I guess that is the case for another question.

Comment: ok, you are welcome